# Implicit Working of Type Casting in Java

Tags: java, typecasting-operator

We often end up using type casting in Java where we cast an Object of one to another in the same hierarchy.

I however could not find any material explaining how type casting worked implicitly.

Anyone here who could shed some light please.

Edit:

What I mean to ask is, given the code
Superclass a = new Subclass(); // no cast needed
Subclass b = (Subclass) a; // cast required

How does Java do the type casting from type SuperClass to SubClass.

While most posts say that Java automatically does it, I was a little curious to know what does it do automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by *implicit* type casting?

Comment: The only implicit casting for reference types (excluding Autoboxing on the assorted primitive wrappers) is "*upcasting*" which is really just application of the inversion of the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: @user2864740 - Oops. My screen didn't refresh.

Comment: @Abhi <br/> some basics here 1) Super type references can always point to sub type objects 2) Java casting works at two levels: at compile time and at runtime <br/> You can see the complete details of this topic in JLS (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html) <br/> Also, look at Generics as to how it provides type safety.

Comment: You don't mean "implicit".  Look the word up in a dictionary ...

Answer (score 3):

For reference types, upcasting is implicit (or at least what I think you mean by *implicit*—that's not standard Java terminology). There is no implicit down-casting. So if you have `Superclass` base class and a `Subclass` class that extends `Superclass`, you can do this:

```
Subclass a = new Subclass();
Superclass b = a; // no cast needed.
```

However, for this:

```
Superclass a = new Subclass(); // no cast needed
Subclass b = (Subclass) a; // cast required
```

Note that in general you are at risk of throwing a `ClassCastException` when you downcast unless you can guarantee that the downcast will work. This is typically done by using the `instanceof` operator:

```
Superclass a = new Subclass(); // no cast needed
Subclass b;
if (a instanceof Subclass) {
    b = (Subclass) a; // cast required
} else {
    // handle problem of a being a different subtype of Superclass
}
```

The standard terminology for upcasting is *widening* and for downcasting it is *narrowing* the type.

EDIT (based on edit to question):

I don't know what those posts you cite mean, unless it's the following. In Java, all reference type variables are just that—references. All that's happening when Java executes:

```
Subclass b = (Subclass) a; // cast required
```

is that it is assigning the reference stored in `a` to `b` after first checking that the object referenced by `a` is assignment-compatible with the declared type of `b`. (Note that the above does not mean that the object is of the same type as `b`—it could be a subtype.) The object itself is not converted in any way to a new object structure. Any changes you make to the internals object through `b` will be seen if you then access the object through `a` (provided the changes affect the more abstract view of the object represented by `a`). In a sense, `a` and `b` are aliases (usually with different public apis) to the same object.

You will get a run-time error if the compatibility check fails. You will get a compile-time error if the check could not possibly succeed. Thus, you cannot get this past the compiler:

```
String x = "Hello world";
Integer y = (Integer) x; // compiler error
```

The aliasing described above does not happen when casting primitive values—such as from `int` to `long`. In those cases, Java will generate a new copy of the value in the machine representation of the cast type.

Comment: Sorry for the terminology. I have edited the question to elaborate further. What I intended to ask was what does Java exactly do to cast one class type to another when it does Subclass b = (Subclass) a;